# How do I get the Parent container to span the total width of my page

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using React and this should be a very simple task yet I am stuck. I cannot get the home container to span the width of my page [image: what is displaying on page]

Here is my Css code, I originally had two Css files one for the Nav and one for the Home section but started playing around trying to figure out where I went wrong. I have basically now stripped my css and code it all the way down  still cant figure out why it wont span completely  from side to side

```
    * {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.site-title {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.nav {
    background-color: #333;
    color: antiquewhite;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
    gap: 2rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.nav ul{
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav a{
    display: flex;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .55rem;

}

.nav li.active {
    background-color: #555;
}

.nav li:hover{
   background-color: #777;
}

.home-container {
  
 background-color: #111;
   
  }


.home-parent {
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: aliceblue;
  }
```

My HTML

```
import Typical from "react-typical";
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home-container">
      <div className="home-parent">
        <div className="profile-details">
          <div className="colz">
            <div className="colz-icon">
              <a href="#">
                <i className="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i className="fa fa-instagram"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i className="fa fa-youtube-square"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i className="fa fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="Home-details-name">
            <span className="primary-text">
              {""}
              Hello, I'm <span className="highlighted-text">Heather</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="home-details-role">
            <span className="primary-text">
              {""}
              <h1>
                <Typical
                  loop={Infinity}
                  steps={[
                    "Fullstack Dev",
                    1000,
                    "Web Design",
                    1000,
                    "Data bases",
                    1000,
                    "Tech Support",
                    1000,
                  ]}
                />
              </h1>
              <span className="home-role-tagline">
                Knack for building applications with front and backend
                operations
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="profile-options">
            <button className="btn primary-btn">
              {""}
              Hire Me{""}
            </button>
            <a
              href="Heather-Christensen.pdf"
              download="Heather-Christensen.pdf"
            >
              <button className="btn highlighted-btn">Get Resume</button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="profile-picture">
          <div className="profile-picture-background"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should show your html as well

Comment: Share your markup

Comment: This isn't a React question. Show rendered HTML, please. Not JSX. Put it and your CSS in a demo snippet using the editor.

Comment: shared, sorry I missed

Comment: That's not HTML.

Comment: The element shown with class 'home-container' reaches the edges on the browser I'm using so I'm assuming on your machine it's rendered within another block level element with a margin or padding. Use the browser inspector to find out what that element is and see how that's styled.

Comment: So when I inspect it definitely has an additional div named container, why does it do this when that container is not in my code? how do i fix that ?

Comment: I tried giving the styling I have for the home-container to the container but that did not work.